# как сделать так, чтобы python видел числа: 00, 01, 02 и тд. как значение int?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Работаю с функцией где нужно взять из стрончого значения ("20508270244") 2 и 3 цифру, преобразовать в int и работать уже со значением инт. Можно ли их взять как str и поставить вместе (например 0 + 5 = 05) и перевести в int?. Просто впоследствии нужно совместить эти цифры с первой, где (2 = 18) и получить год 1805 (так же в значении int).

Comment: `int('18' + s[1:3])` где `s` - строка, содержащая заданное число?

Comment: если вы пробуете `int('05')`, то что у вас получается?

Comment: пишет просто 5...

Comment: ему не сделать проще? `18 * 100 + 5 = 1805`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете это сделать одним из 3х способов:

1. Вытащить это число как строку и сохранить отдельно. По необходимости можно перевести его в int во временной переменной и работать с int. Например:

   ```
   tmp_str = "20508270244"
   str_number = tmp_str[1:3]
   int_number = int(tmp_str)
   ....
   сделать что вам надо с числом
   ...
   str(18) + str_number
   ```
2. Второй - вытащить каждое число в отдельную переменную:

   ```
   number1 = int(tmp_str[1])
   number2 = int(tmp_str[2])
   ....
   Сделать магию с ними
   result = "18" + str(number1) + str(number2)
   ```
3. Можно форматировать число, если оно меньше 2х цифр, но должно быть всегда 2 числа. Например,

   ```
   >>> str(5).zfill(2)
   '05'
   ```

Конечно это можно улучшить и ускорить, но все зависит от того, что именно вам надо.

Сохранить же число в int в виде "05" - нельзя совсем.

Answer (score 0):

Удобно собрать логику в класс:

```
class MyInt:
    def __init__(self, nmb):
        self.bb = nmb[1:3]
        self.bb_int = int(nmb[1:3])

    def add_century(self, a):
        return a*100 + self.bb_int

t = "20508270244"
age_dict = {"2": 18}
q = MyInt(t)
w = q.add_century(age_dict[t[0]])
print q.bb, type(q.bb)
print q.bb_int, type(q.bb_int)
print w, type(w)
# 05 <type 'str'>
# 5 <type 'int'>
# 1805 <type 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Примените метод `format()` для стриоки `"{:02}{:02}"`

```
num1 = 18     # int
num2 = 5      # int

result = int("{:02}{:02}".format(num1, num2))
```

или в Питоне 3.6+ тоже возможно использовать вместо того просто f-строку:

```
result = int(f"{num1:02}{num2:02}")
```

В обоих случаях будет в переменной `result` целое число

> ```
> 1885
> ```

так как спецификатор `:02` сделает из целого числа 2-местную строку, в случае *1-циферного числа дополнен слева нулем*.